# How to use solr's DIH deltaimport to import mysql data which exported by nutch

Tags: mysql, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I want to use solr's DIH deltaimport to import mysql data which exported by nutch, but the mysql data from nutch don't have timestamp field.
The reason I try to import from Mysql is that I want to combine the crawl data to other url management table.
The "modifiedTime" field in the crawl data is bigInt not timeStamp and is always Null.
I examined about this question and I thought that the index filter plugin could solve this problem. Is it right?

nutch 2.1
Solr 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Trying to Use ScriptTransformer to transform each ununiform data before index,I hope this URL will be usefull for you：http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw the reference URL but the delta import on DIH seems to be done before the transform. mysql->transformerm->DIH  can be done?

Comment: I solved it by updating the solr to 2.x patched for modifiedTime and using FROM_UNIXTIME(TRUNCATE(modifiedTime,-3)/1000) in deltaQuery.